# Without choosing bases, how to show that the determinant is multiplicative in this sense?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, exterior-algebra

I was recently considering this statement:

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space, and let $\phi:V\to V$ be an endomorphism. Suppose that $W\subseteq V$ is a subspace that is stable under $\phi$, i.e. such that $\phi(W)\subseteq W$.
>
> Let $\psi:W\to W$ be the restriction of $\phi$ to $W$, and let $\rho:(V/W)\to(V/W)$ be the induced map on the quotient space $V/W$. Then
>   $$\det(\phi)=\det(\psi)\det(\rho).$$

I came up with a proof, but it required choosing bases (ick!): if $\{w_1,\ldots,w_r\}$ is a basis for $W$, and $\{v_1,\ldots,v_s\}$ a set in $V$ that maps down to a basis of $V/W$, then their union $\{w_1,\ldots,w_r,v_1,\ldots,v_s\}$ is a basis for $V$. Expressing $\phi$ as a matrix in this basis, it is a block matrix of the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\ 0 & C
\end{bmatrix}$$
because $\phi(W)\subseteq W$. But $A$ is the $r\times r$ matrix representing the action of $\psi$ on $W$, and $C$ is the $s\times s$ matrix representing the action of $\rho$ on $V/W$, and by properties of block matrices, we have
$$\det(\phi)=\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\ 0 & C
\end{bmatrix}\right)=\det(A)\det(C)=\det(\psi)\det(\rho).$$

---

All well and good, but can someone tell me how to prove this statement the "right" way (via the exterior power functor, exact sequences, etc.?)

Comment: [This passage](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FD4Em.png) is from Bourbaki's *Algebra I: Chapters 1-3*, p.515. It indicates the natural isomorphism of graded algebras $\Lambda(M\oplus N)\cong\Lambda(M)\otimes\Lambda(N)$. So in this sense, the natural fact is that the determinant of the linear map $(\psi\oplus\rho)$ on the space $W\oplus(V/W)$ is equal to the product of the determinant of $\psi$ and the determinant of $\rho$, and then the fact that the determinant is basis-independent means that no matter what isomorphism $V\cong W\oplus(V/W)$ we choose, the determinant will be the same on $V$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lateness of this answer gives a new meaning to the word "overdue". In any case, I noticed this question while browsing this website and I thought I'd answer it because that's what you do when you're faced with a question right?

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for; it's basically equivalent to your basis-dependent proof above and it's based on the section of the Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Direct_sums .

The short exact sequence of vector spaces:

(1) $0\to W\to V\to V/W\to 0$

results in a natural isomorphism:

(2) $\bigwedge^{k} V\cong \bigwedge^{i} W\otimes \bigwedge^{j} V/W$

where $k$, $i$, and $j$ are the dimensions of $V$, $W$, and $V/W$, respectively. The endomorphism of (1) (in the category of short exact sequences of vector spaces) given by the triple $(\psi,\phi,\rho)$ induces an endomorphism of (2) (i.e., a commutative diagram!). The commutativity of this commutative diagram (I hope this isn't bad grammar!) combined with the characterisation of the determinant via the top exterior power results in the equation $\det \phi = \det \psi \det \rho$.

Does that answer your question? The only thing I've done really is inserted fancy terms like "isomorphism", "short exact sequence", and "exterior power" in your proof ...

**Edit**: The isomorphism (2) can be derived by using the fact that (1) splits; see the comments below. Of course, (1) splits because every object in the abelian category of vector spaces over a field is free. In some sense, this is using the existence of a basis for each finite dimensional vector space (choosing a splitting of (1) is equivalent to choosing a basis of the vector space $V/W$). So, you might object that this proof is "nasty" because it involves choices (and I agree).

Ultimately, I suppose the question is to "hide" any use of choices of bases because this is what other apparently "basis-independent" proofs in linear algebra do. The approach is to introduce a construction which "collects" all choices. (If there's no natural choice in mathematics, then you just take them all! Sadly, this is something we can't do in real life.) In some sense, this is what the exterior algebra characterization of the determinant does.

Comment: You could say "The commutativity of this diagram combined...".

Comment: @RagibZaman Yes, that's true though I wanted to emphasise that I was talking about the diagram referred to in the previous sentence. Of course, there are grammatically correct ways of doing this; but somehow the "wrong way" of writing this sentence sounds better!

Comment: @Amitesh: +1, and thanks for taking the time to answer this question :) I'm sure I'm missing something, but could you explain in more detail how the SES in (1) gives rise to the isomorphism in (2)?

Comment: @ZevChonoles Zev, thanks for asking this question because it is indeed subtle! I should give more thought to this but here's my initial observation. The short exact sequence (1) splits because we're dealing with vector spaces. Let's fix a splitting $f:V/W\to V$. Once we've done this, we've basically written down an (unfortunately, non-canonical!) isomorphism $V\cong V\oplus V/W$. Exterior powers respect direct sums in the sense that (2) now holds (and we can write down an isomorphism using the splitting map $f$) ...

Comment: @ZevChonoles ... Although the splitting isn't natural, it's natural with respect to the endomorphism of (1) given by the triple $(\psi,\phi,\rho)$. So, I think the rest of the argument goes through without difficulty. If we agree this proof is good, it's still unsatisfying because we need to do something unnatural, that is, pick a splitting $f:V/W\to V$. The question is whether we need to do this ...

Comment: @ZevChonoles ... I'll think about this more but it's a possibility that the freeness of $V/W$ (which is what we're using to get a splitting) is something fundamentally necessary here; that is, the result we're trying to prove doesn't hold for arbitrary (non-free) modules over a general commutative ring. If that's the case, it would be interesting to come up with a counterexample. But like I said, choosing a splitting basically amounts to doing exactly the unnatural thing in your proof that you weren't satisfied with initially. If a counterexample exists, that would vindicate the un-naturality.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Actually, I just gave some thought to what I said above and I don't know what I was talking about because I I don't know how to define the determinant of an endomorphism of a non-free module over a general commutative ring! So, no counterexample to which I was alluding exists. I'll have to think more about whether it's possible not to use a splitting ...

Comment: You also inserted "natural", which was key.

Comment: @Amitesh: Thanks again for all of your help on this question! Would you be able to explain or give a detailed reference for the isomorphism in (2), disregarding the splitting issue? That is, why exactly does a direct sum
$$A\cong B\oplus C$$
induce an isomorphism
$$\Lambda^{\dim(A)}A\cong \Lambda^{\dim(B)}B\otimes \Lambda^{\dim(C)}C$$
for vector spaces $A,B,C$?

Comment: Hi @Zev, you're welcome! I think the bilinear map $\Lambda^{\dim B}\times \Lambda^{\dim C} C$ defined by the rule $(b_1\wedge\cdots\wedge b_{\dim B})\times (c_1\wedge\cdots\wedge c_{\dim C})\to \text{Alt}(b_1\wedge\cdots\wedge b_{\dim B}\wedge c_1\wedge\cdots\wedge c_{\dim C})$ induces a linear isomorphism $\Lambda^{\dim B}\otimes \Lambda^{\dim C} C\to \Lambda^{\dim A} A$. ($\text{Alt}$ means "alternatization".) Does that answer your question? (I think you can prove it's an isomorphism by explicitly writing down an inverse; I can add that detail if you like but it's cumbersome to write down.)

Answer (score 0):

One way to see this is to interpret the determinant as the unique map between exterior powers which is normalized to send the identity map to $1$.

In other words $\det$ is the unique alternating multilinear map $\text{Mat}_n(F)\to F$ (where we interpret $\text{Mat}_n(F)$ as $n$ column vectors). The association

$$\phi\mapsto (\psi,\rho)\mapsto \det(\psi)\det(\rho)$$

is also seen to enjoy this property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I see how your proposal works; I agree with the characterization of the determinant, but how can we say that a map to $F$ from the space of endomorphisms of $V$ is "multilinear" without choosing a basis? Perhaps I'm missing something - could you fill in some more details?

Answer (score 0):

In geometric (or Clifford) algebra, the determinant of a linear map from vectors to vectors is obtained through "outermorphism".  Given a linear map $\underline \phi$, there is a natural extension of this map to arbitrary $k$-vectors given by

$$\underline \phi(a_1 \wedge a_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge a_k) = \underline \phi(a_1) \wedge \underline \phi(a_2) \wedge \ldots \wedge \underline \phi(a_k)$$

for $k$ distinct vectors $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$.

An $n$-dimensional vector space has a pseudoscalar that characterizes it.  This *can* be formed by taking wedge products of basis vectors.  However, as the vector space of pseudoscalars is 1-dimensional, all pseudoscalars are scalar multiples of all others.  The pseduoscalar is an $n$-vector.

Choose some pseudoscalar for the space and denote it $i$.  Then the determinant is the number $f$ such that

$$\underline \phi(i) = f i$$

Again, it follows that there is only one such number because $i$ is a member of a 1d vector space.

In GA parlance, you're talking about a linear map being decomposed into eigenblades.  There is a blade $W$ and its complement $W^\perp = iW^{-1}$.  You know that $\underline \phi(W) = \alpha W$ for some scalar $\alpha$.

Define a projection map $\underline P(a)$ such that $\underline P(a) \wedge W = 0$.  Similarly, there is a rejection map $\underline P^\perp(a)$ such that $\underline P^\perp(a) \wedge W^\perp = 0$.  Of course, $\underline P + \underline P^\perp = \underline I$, the identity.

Break down the original map $\underline \phi$ as follows:

$$\underline \phi(a) = [\underline P + \underline P^\perp] \underline \phi[ \underline P + \underline P^\perp](a) = [\underline{P \phi P} + \underline{P^\perp \phi P^\perp} + \underline{P \phi P^\perp} + \underline{P^\perp \phi P}](a)$$

The first two terms are the maps $\underline \psi$ and $\underline \rho$ that you defined, so the breakdown is

$$\underline \phi(a) = \underline \psi(a) + \underline \rho(a) + \underline{P^\perp \phi P}(a) + \underline{P \phi P^\perp}(a)$$

Now, we said quite specifically that $\phi(W) = \alpha W$.  That means that third term, $\underline{P^\perp \phi P}$, is exactly zero (the zero block you observed in matrix form).  Now we can take the full determinant by seeing that $i = W^\perp \wedge W$.

$$\underline \phi(i) = \underline \phi(W^\perp) \wedge \underline \phi(W) = [\underline \rho(W^\perp) + \underline{P \phi}(W^\perp)] \wedge [\underline \psi(W)] = [\underline \rho(W^\perp) + \underline{P \phi}(W^\perp)] \wedge [\alpha W]$$

Now, we'll get a term that is $\underline{P \phi}(W^\perp) \wedge [\alpha W]$.  This is zero, as the projection $\underline P$ will force that term to lie within the subspace of $W$, and $W \wedge W= 0$ always.  This leaves us with

$$\underline \phi(i) = [\underline \rho(W^\perp)] \wedge [\underline \psi(W)]$$

Identity $W^\perp$ acts like the pseudoscalar for $\underline \rho$, just as $W$ acts as a pseudoscalar for $\underline \psi$. The result is

$$\underline \phi(i) = (\det \underline \rho) W^\perp \wedge (\det \psi) W = (\det \underline \rho)(\det \underline \psi) W^\perp W$$

And again, $W^\perp W = i$, so we're done.  I think the big key is using the projection/rejection maps to get a basis-independent statement of the block matrix form.  The Clifford algebra means of talking about determinants makes it more obvious that you can take the determinants of these restricted maps because you need only supply the correct pseudoscalar for the map to get its determinant.  It also lets us break down the determinant as the wedge of $W^\perp$ and $W$ in a basis independent way.

To carry out this calculation, you *do* have to choose some pseudoscalar $i$, but this is much relaxed compared to choosing a basis.  You could always choose a pseudoscalar that is unit, for instance.